# How to add floating image without making CSS3 multicolumn div narrower?

Tags: css, css-float

As one can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZP3vu/ text becames bit narrower because of floating image, then backs to 100% width beneath the image. However with CSS3 multi-column it becomes ugly: http://jsfiddle.net/QLFav/

What can I do to prevent image from making multicolumn content so narrow? To have that blank space below image filled with text?

[image: http://jsfiddle.net/ZP3vu/]
[image: http://jsfiddle.net/QLFav/]