# wrap multi-column div around image

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

This question is almost identical to [How to add floating image without making CSS3 multicolumn div narrower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270724/how-to-add-floating-image-without-making-css3-multicolumn-div-narrower), which was not answered.

I have a multi-column div that I want to wrap around an image that will float in the top right of the page.  The problem is that the text in the multi-column div does not wrap, even though the div is set to float.

Should look like:

```
|-||-|xxxxxx
|-||-|xxxxxx
|-||-|xxxxxx
|-||-||-||-|
|-||-||-||-|
```

Currently looks like:

```
      xxxxxx
      xxxxxx
      xxxxxx
|-||-||-||-|
|-||-||-||-|
|-||-||-||-|
```

The HTML:

```
<img src="something.png"/>
<div>some really long text</div>
```

The CSS:

```
img {
    float: right;
    clear:none;
}
div {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;

    -moz-column-width:157px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-width:157px; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-width:157px;

    float:left;
    clear:none;
}
```

I have a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/JpcM4/2/

The challenge is that I do not know how much text is going to be in the div, and I do not know how wide the image is.  That means I can't just have four divs for four columns and float them separately, since I don't know what text is in each column or even which columns will be shortened by the image.

I also looked at column-span and -webkit-column-span (which would not work for Firefox anyway), but it seems that's not what I'd thought: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

Comment: The reason your text is dropping below the image is that is doesn't have an explicit width and the default width for a `<div>` is 100%. Unfortunately, if the width is small enough to fit next to the image, you're stuck with that width for the whole `<div>`, so no text appears directly underneath the image.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JpcM4/4/) fiddle.  I removed `column-count`s and `column-width`s from `div`.  I did this, because unfortunately not *all* columns can fit to the left of the **div,** so you cannot have text directly underneath it.  [Here's](http://css-tricks.com/float-center/) a small hack to do it, because it cannot be done *purely* in css, so the hack is to create two different **divs:** one on the left, and one on the right (`float:left` and other underneath).

```
.thumbimage {
    float: right;
    clear:none;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

Comment: The fiddle is gone.